# How to get value from Promise { string }? I am using https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper/

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper/ to **scrape** some data. My code is

```
const TikTokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');
a = (async () => {
    try {
        let videoMeta = await TikTokScraper.getVideoMeta('https://www.tiktok.com/@nishaguragain/video/6823736724821216513');
        return videoMeta
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

I am getting this after running the function.

```
    > a
Promise {
  { id: '6823736724821216513',
    text:
     'Bina bataye  video start kar diya#@deepakjoshi.102 #stayhome #foryou #nishaguragainfam',
    createTime: '1588775017',
    authorMeta: { id: '242395344267849728', name: 'nishaguragain' },
    musicMeta:
     { musicId: '6595720952414210822',
       musicName: 'I nerver thought she could dance like this',
       musicAuthor: 'flighthouse' },
    imageUrl:
     'https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/47436416b93b4cd1ac0b7ed0c17c6ba3_1588775020?x-expires=1598338800&x-signature=KvfbQJwk0jCmNaJwKeae719duq4%3D',
    videoUrl:
     'https://v16m.tiktokcdn.com/240a38ca388d5f719e0998bc625a77e8/5f44be52/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c001/cbbcb564b09a4c66a58fe8365a98b99b/?a=1233&br=7528&bt=3764&cr=0&cs=0&dr=0&ds=3&er=&l=2020082307313001011603423405001013&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&qs=0&rc=ajxxM3l1czNmdDMzODczM0ApNDk3ZzZnZGRmNzplaDc4PGdlYi9nZmNkZG1fLS0zMTZzczA2MS1iMTQ2XzMxXmMzL2E6Yw%3D%3D&vl=&vr=',
    videoUrlNoWaterMark:
     'https://api2-16-h2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=v09044650000bqpcg0gpfrivj02ne9hg&vr_type=0&is_play_url=1&source=PackSourceEnum_PUBLISH&media_type=4',
    videoMeta: { width: 540, height: 960, ratio: 13, duration: 13 },
    covers:
     { default:
        'https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/41374d9703a34cbb82e61c2fccf3d36c_1588775020?x-expires=1598338800&x-signature=M%2FlqnSTqPPF%2BxBj%2BZqZNmg7wmBM%3D',
       origin:
        'https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/47436416b93b4cd1ac0b7ed0c17c6ba3_1588775020?x-expires=1598338800&x-signature=KvfbQJwk0jCmNaJwKeae719duq4%3D' },
    diggCount: 938500,
    shareCount: 2649,
    playCount: 10600000,
    commentCount: 2213,
    downloaded: false,
    mentions: [ '@deepakjoshi' ],
    hashtags: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

How can i get value of imageUrl: that is https://p16-sign-va.tiktokcdn.com/obj/tos-maliva-p-0068/47436416b93b4cd1ac0b7ed0c17c6ba3_1588775020?x-expires=1598338800&x-signature=KvfbQJwk0jCmNaJwKeae719duq4%3D in a variable to use in future.

When i am typing videoMeta it is showing
Thrown:
ReferenceError: videoMeta is not defined
[videoMeta is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Agwk.png)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdsqU.png)

Comment: Maybe unfair this question was closed against those particular answers, if it relates to the NodeJS REPL. However it wasn't stated if solving it in the REPL was the aim. The linked answers should solve the problem for script code, but for REPL code you might want to use the `--experimental-repl-await` flag when launching the Node REPL. This will permit you to easily get the resolved value from a promise using a 'top level' await in the REPL. See https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_await_keyword for more information.

Comment: None of the above post helps me in my situation.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Habib. Are you comfortable with what the `await` keyword does and how it relates to a Promise ? A Promise is a wrapper around a future value. When the value finally arrives, you still have to unwrap it, which is what `await` does. So for example in the context of your REPL you would be able to type `resolvedA = await a; resolvedA.videoMeta` . However, to do this in the Node REPL, you have to launch node with explicit support for being able to use the `await` keyword interactively.

Comment: At that time, I was a beginning my journey in Javascript. Thank You for your response. I got mysef enrolled for the JS course and leraned too many new things(Keywords).